# Create Django objects in step increments

Tags: django, django-models, factory-boy

I'm trying to write a function to create total number of Django objects in step increments. Note, I'm using [factory-boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to generate the fake data. Here is what I have come up with:

```
def create_todos_in_batch(total, step):
    quotient, remainder = divmod(total, step)
    for i in range(quotient):
        print(f"Inserting {i * step:,} to {(i + 1) * step:,}")
        todos = TodoFactory.build_batch(step)
        Todo.objects.bulk_create(todos)
    if remainder:
        print(f"Inserting {total - remainder:,} to {total:,}")
        todos = TodoFactory.build_batch(remainder)
        Todo.objects.bulk_create(todos)
```

To create 100 objects in 20 object increments, the function can be called like so:

```
create_todos_in_batch(100, 20)
```

I have the following unit test to prove this works correctly:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "total, step",
    [
        (100, 20),
        (1_000, 100),
        (10_000, 1_000),
    ],
)
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_in_batch(total, step):
    create_todos_in_batch(total=total, step=step)
    count = Todo.objects.count()
    assert count == total, f"{count:,} != {total:,}"
```

Is there a better way to write this function? I feel like this is too verbose because I'm repeating `TodoFactory.build_batch()` and `Todo.objects.bulk_create(todos)` multiple times.

Comment: Wouldn't separating those two lines into a create_todos(amount) function solve the problem, or are you looking specifically for something within the existing function?

Comment: I'm thinking there may be a cleaner way of writing this without using `divmod`